# Javascript - Create a method dynamically?

Tags: javascript

```
dynobj = {};
methods = ["method1","method2", "method3"];
for (var i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
    dynobj[methods[i]] = function () {
      alert("I am " + i);
    };
};
dynobj.method2();
dynobj.method1();
```

I expect "I am 1" and "I am 0", but have "I am 3" and "I am 3". What the correct way to have behaveary which I expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var dynobj = {};

var methods = ["method1", "method2", "method3"];

var length = methods.length;

for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    dynobj[methods[i]] = (function (i) {
        return function () {
            alert("I am " + i);
        };
    }(i));
}

dynobj.method2();
dynobj.method1();
```

See the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3Fxv5/